# Regex required for parsing text into object

Tags: regex

Hey guys i am sharing some snippet of text where i need to parse address key text.

```
PAYER:\r\n\r\n   Con\r\n\r\nPROVIDER:\r\n\r\n   YAHAN \r\n   Provider ID: 11544974\r\n\r\nINSURED:\r\n\r\n   MICHELEEE WCK\r\n   Member ID: 134557001\r\n   Address:\r\n      9 CRESCENT OAK\r\n      MISRI CITY, TX 174\r\n   Birth Date: 05/22/1990\r\n
```

**REGEX +  CODE**

```
const obj = {},
  re = new RegExp("(.*?):\r\n(.*?)(?:\r\n)", "g");

y.replace(re, (_, key, value) => {
  obj[key.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "").toLowerCase()] = value.trim();
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: please share your attempt before asking [mcve]

Comment: I am using this => regex re = new RegExp("(.*?):\r\n(.*?)(?:\r\n)", "g"); as of now which couldn't extract TX 744

Comment: here's my result:

{
  payer: '',
  provider: '',
  insured: '',
  address: '1403 CRESCENT OAK DR',
  patient: '',
  coveragetype: '',
  coveragedates: '',

}

Comment: @depperm shared pal

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @depperm javascript

Comment: But what do you expect to get and why? Please add all relevant details to the question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i just want to get an object from the provided text and thats all in key value form just likes this = {address: '1103 CRESCENT OAK DR\r\n      MISRI CITY, TX 774'}

Comment: can you edit the question and add your regex and js code, with what you expect to get and why

Comment: @depperm i already posted my regex in comments. but here it is new RegExp("(.*?):\r\n(.*?)(?:\r\n)", "g")

Comment: it should be part of the question, so other users don't have to read the comments. Also please add your code (js)

Comment: I want to create an object by text that i posted here. i want an object which just like this: {address: '1103 CRESCENT OAK DR\r\n MISRI CITY, TX 774'} - \r\n should be removed

Comment: @depperm code added in question as well as regex

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/sebaxnpy/, is it what you expect?

Comment: What is the format of the address? I see indenting spaces as well and only uppercase chars. Can there be colons in the address as well? https://regex101.com/r/x71FKE/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How can i marked you reply as an answered?

Comment: I posted the answer below.

Comment: Okay i marked an answered. Once again thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const regex = /(.*?):[\r\n]*(.*(?:\r?\n {4}.*)*)/g;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNab1F/1). Details:

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `:` - a colon
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more linebreaks
- `(.*(?:\r?\n {4}.*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `(?:\r?\n {4}.*)*` - zero or more sequences of a CRLF/LF line break and then four spaces and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'PAYER:\r\n\r\n   United Con\r\n\r\nPROVIDER:\r\n\r\n   YAR KHAN \r\n   Provider ID: 11544974\r\n\r\nINSURED:\r\n\r\n   MICHELLE WICK\r\n   Member ID: 134557001\r\n   Address:\r\n      1103 CRESCENT OAK DR\r\n      MISRI CITY, TX 774\r\n   Birth Date: 05/22/1980\r\n';
const regex = /(.*?):[\r\n]*(.*(?:\r?\n {4}.*)*)/g;
let obj = {}, m;
while( m=regex.exec(text) ) {
  obj[m[1].trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ").toLowerCase()] = m[2].trim();
}
console.log(obj)
```